# Rails 4 - ActionController can't require 2 keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

Looking at [the documentation for ActionController::Parameters for the `require` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) I read the followiing

> When given an array of keys, the method tries to require each one of them in order. If it succeeds, an array with the respective return values is returned:
>
> ```
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { ... }, profile: { ... })
> user_params, profile_params = params.require(:user, :profile)
> ```

but when I run this code with `rails console`, my output is very different

```
[70] pry(main)> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { a: 1 }, profile: { b: 2 })
=> {"user"=>{"a"=>1}, "profile"=>{"b"=>2}}
[71] pry(main)> user_params, profile_params = params.require(:user, :profile)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:244:in `require'
```

When I read `when given an array of keys` and saw the example, I thought that maybe they made a mistake when writing the example, so I tried this as well, but it did not work either.

```
[72] pry(main)> user_params, profile_params = params.require([:user, :profile])
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: [:user, :profile]
from /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in `require'
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the API docs for the current version of Rails (which is Rails 5), and you're using Rails 4.2.1. The Rails 4 docs do not specify multiple arguments to `require` like that:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

Comment: OUCH! Thanks for that! Do you happen to know a way to achieve that on Rails 4?

Comment: unfortunately I don't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
def user_params
 params.require(:user)
end

def profile_params
 params.require(:profile)
end
```

This way you have two separate rules for each model.